# Project Web App is stuck on: Waiting for resources

Tags: sql-server, project-server, provisioning, pwa

While trying to unprovision a PWA in order to move the DB to a new SQL Server. I followed the following [article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff961887(v=office.14).aspx)

After the "Delete" phase of the Project, it's stuck in

```
" Waiting for Resources" - (That's step #4 in : To unprovision the PWA site)
```

[image]

The server is at this for over 24 hours already. How can I release this ?

**Note :** The server is a Virtual Machine (if it makes any diff)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Timer service was stopped and in Manual.

Starting the Timer Service, solved this issue.

Comment: Satrting the Timer Service helped me too.

Comment: Starting the timer service strangely solved this problem without need to restart any service . Don't need to rerun project web app instance wizard.

Answer (score 0):

This problem might occur because of stopping the `SharePoint Timer Service`.

**To start SharePoint Timer Service**

- From start menu > open service.msc.
- Search for SharePoint Timer Service > Start/Restart It.

> **Note:** it's recommended to [Restart SharePoint Timer Service From Command Line](https://spgeeks.devoworx.com/pwa-stuck-on-waiting-for-resources-during-provisioning/#start-sharepoint-timer-service-from-command-line)

> For more details, Please Check this **[PWA stuck on Waiting for Resources in Project Server 2013](https://spgeeks.devoworx.com/pwa-stuck-on-waiting-for-resources-during-provisioning/)**